# Assigning a name to an anonymous function (.name vs .displayName)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am running a react native project, where this function

```
const f = function() {};
```

has an undefined name, not inferred.

Keeping the anonymous definition, is this code:

```
f.name = "f";

console.log(f.name); // f
```

an anti-pattern? Should I use `.displayName` instead?

---

Update (real code, the described one is a simpler version):

```
const MyComponent = forwardRef(({ userId }, ref) => {
  useTrackScreenView(MyComponent.name, {
    user_id: userId,
  });

  return JSX...
});

console.log(MyComponent.name) // undefined

//
// MyComponent.name = "MyComponent"; anti-pattern?
//   or
// MyComponent.displayName = "MyComponent";
//
```

Comment: Take a step back - why is the function name even relevant? Is this [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: @VLAZ In my real code, I am wrapping my React component inside a .forwardRef(), which returns an anonymous funciton. I am tracking the screen_view (Google Analytics) events, that's why I am using the .name property, instead of using literals.

Comment: BTW my problem is exactly as described, I can't change the anonymous assignment.

Comment: I updated the question with my real scenario

Comment: You can just use a named function or set the `displayName` prop [as the docs show](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html#displaying-a-custom-name-in-devtools)

Comment: Not sure what you're doing or in what environment you execute this code, but when I run `const f = function() {};`, then `f.name` is `'f'`. (Ah, thanks for the edit - you use `forwardRef`)

Comment: @Bergi Yes, it's weird. Might be ES5 environment, or something. `.name` is supposed to be read-only anyway and this code 1. doesn't implicitly set it 2. apparently allows changing it.

Answer (score -1):

Using the `@ts-check` directive indicates that the Function's `.name` property is **read-only**.

So, the way to go is using `.displayName`.

Comment: Well you could `Object.defineProperty(MyComponent, 'name', {value: 'MyComponent'})`, but yes that's cumbersome which is why React provides the `displayName` alternative.